# RIA Services : expose services when entities are in a different project from EDMX?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

My Visual Studio solution has the following architecture :

- a "DataAccess" project, containing one EDMX with his "object context" class (but without any generated business class)
- an "Entities" project, containing the business entities **generated from the EDMX**. (ex : Customer class, Order class, Product class, etc).
- a "Web" project containing the ASP.Net GUI.

Now I want to add a small Silverlight area in my existing application, with RIA Services.
I don't succeed in creating the domain Service : the "Add new domain service class" wizard contains my ObjectContext but itself contains no entities. It seems that it's because **the EDMX is NOT in the same assembly as my entities**.

Now I don't want to rebuild my existing application with a new architecture by merging the 2 projects (actual architecture seems clean for me).

How can I make this %$$$! wizard see my entities ? Should I construct the domain service class manually ? How ?

Thanks !

EDIT : I'm using C# (4), EF 4, Silverlight4

EDIT 2 : my entities are generated with the "ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator".

Answer (score 0):

> Should I construct the domain service class manually ?

I reckon so. It's the same using EF 5 with POCOs, the wizard doesn't pick up the entities. There are some helpful [snippets on Colin Blair's site](http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/WCF-RIA-Services-EF-41-and-Snippets.aspx) for creating the CRUD methods over the `DbContext`.